# C Simple Code Involving getchar() and putchar() Unexpected Output

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

As I was following an example from a book,

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
        int c;

        c = getchar();
        while (c != EOF) {   
                putchar(c)
                c = getchar();
        }
}
```

I thought it would make more sense to read character first, then print it so switched putchar and getchar around

```
c = getchar();
putchar(c);
```

now when I run it, what happens is the first output of putchar is missing the first character of c? This is the output:

```
kingvon@KingVon:~/Desktop/C$ ./a.out
first letter is missing?
irst letter is missing?
but now it is not 
but now it is not
```

This is interesting, why does this happen?

Comment: You need a `do{}while();` to do that

Comment: The standard idiom make it a little clearer: `while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){ putchar(c); }`  If you prefer, you could write it `while( c = getchar(), c != EOF ){ putchar(c); }`

Comment: Another problem with your suggested change is that you will call `putchar(EOF)` eventually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're getting a character *before* the loop. That means c is equal to that first character, but in the loop it's getting every character after that. So,

```
Get: f
Start the loop
Get: i
Print: i
And so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that now you're not printing the character that you read with `getchar()` before the loop, so you don't print the first character.

If you want to do the `getchar()` first, put it into the `while()` condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {   
        putchar(c)
    }
}
```